# iOS: Multiple views accessing the same data - how to access?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4

I'm a Java Developer new to iOS and objective c development.

I need to build an iOS application where multiple views (e.g. a ListView and a MapView) access the same data (e.g. stored in an NSArray).

Currently, I do alloc and init a DataManager class that loads the data (loading it from a plist, later it should be requested from the web) in the app delegate.

How do I access this data from the views? Should the DataManager be a singleton? Is there a better/more elegant/more "obj-c 2.0" solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use the MVC architecture. Your data is a *model* object, which can be passed to the various *controllers* that use the data to populate the *views*. In Cocoa Touch, the views are the `UIView` subclasses that you typically create in XIB files. The controllers usually start with `UIViewController` instances that manage the views, but include things like table view delegates and data sources. The models are the objects you create to represent the data - your `DataManager` class.

There are plenty of frameworks in the Java world that use the MVC pattern, so you may already be used to dividing classes up this way if you've come across e.g. Spring MVC, or Eclipse RCP.

Comment: thx, yes i'm familiar with MVC (though i was mostly doing backend EE stuff) - i already have the XIBs and the view controllers, and previously i had the ListViewController provide the data for the table view directly, but now i need to refactor this, since the map view will need access to that data also.